# Admob: Ads show in my older apps but not in my new app

Tags: android, admob

I know there's a lot of questions regarding this issue, but they don't fit my specific case.

---

I have an app in Google Admob with 2 ad units (banner and interstitial). I am using that app from Admob for 5 different apps in the Play Store.

So I use the same App ID, Banner ID, Interstitial ID for all apps in the Play Store, as I use the same app from Google Admob.

It works like a charm for these 5 apps.

---

Now I want to publish another app and I tried to do the exact same thing, so I used the same ad implementation for the ads and again the same App ID, Banner ID, Interstitial ID. (I simply copied all code from the other apps)

But this time, no ads appear. I'm already waiting for ca. 2 weeks for them to appear. One single time I had "luck" and an ad appeared (for whatever reason), but besides that single time, an ad was never shown.

If I use the Test Ad IDs from Admob, all Test ads show. So the implementation is correct.

The Logcat however shows two errors:

`Ad failed to load : 3` and `Ad failed to load : 1` (mostly it's error 3 though)

I looked them up and they mean:

- 3 means that there are no ads filled, so everything is correct, but Admob doesn't have any ads they want me to display right now.
- 1 means that there are some ID errors (e.g. banner ID for the interstitial).

But, to me, both don't make any sense: How don't they have any ads to display when they have always ads to display for the other 5 apps? I mean it's the same app in Google Admob.
And how can there be an ID error when it works with the Test ads and especially it works in the other 5 apps?

I have tried to install the app as a signed APK on my physical device, doesn't change anything (however, on the other apps the ads always appeared even in debugging mode).

---

So I really don't know what could be the problem in this case. As said, I'm already waiting for 2-3 weeks for the ads to show (and I was using the app constantly throughout that time; so ad requests were made constantly). So I don't think it is a matter of time.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried all the tools / links at the bottom of the documentation web page (like https://developers.google.com/admob/android/ad-load-errors)?

Comment: @dominicoder I have tried to implement that and have encountered another weird problem. It's quite like a new problem, so I have asked a new question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894920/android-admob-cannot-import-some-classes

Comment: is your new app linked ? https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10037806?hl=en