# Android Admob: Cannot import some classes

Tags: android, admob

I have used Admob in several projects already, but this time I encounter a strange problem.

I followed all instructions from the official documentary [(here)](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start), and everything basically works, at least the test ads.

---

But I've encountered the problem, that some classes just can't be imported.

For example, when I take this code from the documentation:

```
MobileAds.initialize(act, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                        }
                    });
```

My project just cannot find `OnInitializationCompleteListener`, nor `initializationStatus`. This was never like that in my older projects. `MobileAds` though can be imported just perfectly. (What I did to make it work is just omit the not working part: `MobileAds.initialize(act);`)

Same problem with some other classes as well, e.g. `LoadAdError`, `AdError`, or `ResponseInfo`.
They just cannot be imported.

Android Studio does not give any hints to classes with that name that could be imported and when I add `import XXX` and take XXX from the official documentation as the full class name (with packages), it cannot find that.

---

This is very odd, since first of all, this has never happened before in my projects, and secondly, because only some imports cannot be found.

---

**MY APP BUILD GRADLE**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // proguard stuff

        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    // Firebase Stuff
    ...

    // ads
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, you have to add a dependency on build.gradle. I wrote the dependency below

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
```

Comment: Weird that in my old projects it always worked with the "older" version. But this did fix it, thx